# Count values in column and assign to row

Tags: python, pandas, list, histogram

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    dT_sampleTime   steps      
0        0.002      0.001
1        0.004      0.002
2        0.004      0.003  
3        0.004      0.004  
4        0.003      0.005  
5        0.007      0.006
6        0.001      0.007
```

and I want to count how often the value of steps occurs in the column dT_sampleTime and create a new column absolute frequency.

```
    dT_sampleTime   steps    absolute frequency    
0       0.002       0.001            1              
1       0.004       0.002            1
2       0.004       0.003            1
3       0.004       0.004            3
4       0.003       0.005            0
5       0.007       0.006            0
6       0.001       0.007            1
```

My idea was something like this:

```
df['absolute frequency'] = df.groupby(df['steps'],df['dT_sampleTime']).count
```

Answer (score 1):

`map`  the 'steps' column with the `value_counts` of the 'dt_sampleTime' column. Then fill the missing values with 0.

```
df['absolute frequency'] = (df['steps'].map(df['dT_sampleTime'].value_counts())
                                       .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))

#   dT_sampleTime  steps  absolute frequency
#0          0.002  0.001                   1
#1          0.004  0.002                   1
#2          0.004  0.003                   1
#3          0.004  0.004                   3
#4          0.003  0.005                   0
#5          0.007  0.006                   0
#6          0.001  0.007                   1
```

---

When mapping with a Series it uses the index to look up the appropriate value. The value_counts Series is

```
df['dT_sampleTime'].value_counts()
#0.004    3
#0.007    1
#0.001    1
#0.002    1
#0.003    1
#Name: dT_sampleTime, dtype: int64
```

so `0.004` in the steps columns goes to `3`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

- Loop across `df`
- Use the `steps` value of each row as a filter applied to the `dT_sampleTime` column
- The number of rows in the resultant DataFrame is the absolute frequency of the current `steps` value within the `dt_sampleTime` column
- Append this value to the current row under the `absolute frequency` field

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
     df.loc[i, 'absolute frequency'] = len(df[df['dT_sampleTime'] == row['steps']])
```

Resulting `df` based on the example given in your original question:

```
   dT_sampleTime  steps  absolute frequency
0          0.002  0.001                 1.0
1          0.004  0.002                 1.0
2          0.004  0.003                 1.0
3          0.004  0.004                 3.0
4          0.003  0.005                 0.0
5          0.007  0.006                 0.0
6          0.001  0.007                 1.0
```

I'm not sure that this is the most efficient way to achieve your ends, however it does work quite well and should be suitable for your purpose. Happy to take feedback on this from anybody if they know better and would be so kind.